# Hosting Android apk externally to bypass size restriction

Tags: android, google-play

Is there any one familiar with this "[Externally hosted private apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145182?hl=en&ref_topic=9495939)"? We are planning to host our Android Apk onto Managed Google Play but the apk size is around 300mb, it is way too much over the allowable size which is 100mb. We are not able to externalize the assets at the moment, so we are thinking to go for this "Externally hosted private apps", it sounds like it allows to by-pass size limit because we are hosting the apk on our premise and only the metadata is uploaded onto Managed Google Play. I can't find any doc saying the size limit though. Is there anyone is using this way and could you please share some information?